# Как скопировать все файлы в один?

Tags: linux, файлы, unix, текстовые-файлы

Помогите пожалуйста с командой, нужно сделать копирование всех `.txt`-файлов в одном файле (`"**cp *.txt 1.txt**"`)     — не работает **cp**. Работает, только когда копируем всего лишь один файл в другой, или когда хотим все файлы копировать в директорию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cat *.txt > outfile

Comment: А если хочется разделить их все красивыми заголовочками, то `more *.txt > outfile`